# ExtJS Load local json file into tree panel

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs5

I want to do a tree that load information from a json local file, with the code that i have the tree load the node parent but the child node doesn't load, is something missing in my code?

Model:

```
Ext.define('modeloCapa', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['nombre', 'capas', 'capa']
});
```

Store:

```
var treeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'modeloCapa',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: "jsontestq.json",  
        reader: {
            type    : 'json',
            root    : 'Result'
        }
    }
});
```

Tree panel:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Prueba',
    width: 500,
    height: 550,
    store: treeStore,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn', 
        text: 'Col1',
        flex: 2,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'nombre'
    }]
});
```

Json file:

```html
{"Result":[{
"nombre":"Transporte Marítimo Fluvial ",
"id":74,
 "capas":[{
  "id":268,
  "capa":{
   "id":268,
   "titulo":"puerto_p_25k",
   "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
   "nombre":"puerto_p_25k",
   "metadato":"",
   "wfs":false
  }
 }]
},{
"nombre":"Entidades Territoriales y Unidades Admin ",
"id":65,
 "capas":[{
  "id":239,
  "capa":{
   "id":239,
   "titulo":"limite_25k",
   "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
   "nombre":"limite_25k",
   "metadato":"",
   "wfs":false
  }
 },{
  "id":319,
  "capa":{
   "id":319,
   "titulo":"administrativo_p_25k",
   "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
   "nombre":"administrativo_p_25k",
   "metadato":"",
   "wfs":false
  }
 }]
},{
"nombre":"Instalaciones Construcciones  para el Transporte ",
"id":67,
 "capas":[{
  "id":269,
  "capa":{
  "id":269,
  "titulo":"red_alta_tension_25k",
  "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
  "nombre":"red_alta_tension_25k",
  "metadato":"",
  "wfs":false
  }
 },{
  "id":260,
  "capa":{
   "id":260,
   "titulo":"peaje_25k",
   "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
   "nombre":"peaje_25k",
   "metadato":"",
   "wfs":false
  }
 },{
  "id":275,
  "capa":{
   "id":275,
   "titulo":"torre_25k",
   "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
   "nombre":"torre_25k",
   "metadato":"",
   "wfs":false
  }
 },{
  "id":266,
  "capa":{
  "id":266,
  "titulo":"puente_l_25k",
  "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
  "nombre":"puente_l_25k",
  "metadato":"",
  "wfs":false
  }
 },{
  "id":267,
  "capa":{
   "id":267,
   "titulo":"puente_p_25k",
   "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
   "nombre":"puente_p_25k",
   "metadato":"",
   "wfs":false
  }
 },{
  "id":259,
  "capa":{
   "id":259,
   "titulo":"paso_nivel_25k",
   "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
   "nombre":"paso_nivel_25k",
   "metadato":"",
   "wfs":false
  }
 },{ 
  "id":223,
  "capa":{
   "id":223,
   "titulo":"antena_25k",
   "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
   "nombre":"antena_25k",
   "metadato":"",
   "wfs":false
  }
 },{ 
  "id":273,
  "capa":{
   "id":273,
   "titulo":"terminal_p_25k",
   "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
   "nombre":"terminal_p_25k",
   "metadato":"",
   "wfs":false
  }
 },{ 
  "id":265,
  "capa":{
   "id":265,
   "titulo":"poste_25k",
   "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
   "nombre":"poste_25k",
   "metadato":"",
   "wfs":false
  }
 },{
  "id":276,
  "capa":{
   "id":276,
   "titulo":"tuberia_25k",
   "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
   "nombre":"tuberia_25k",
   "metadato":"",
   "wfs":false
  }
 }]}]
}
```

Thanks for suggest.

Comment: Maybe your json file doesn't provide the right properties. Child elements must be placed in the "children" sub array. Take a look here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel.

Comment: Thanks, there are any way to do the tree with this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bit messed up json data for your tree.

I've simplified your json for better understanding:

```
{"Result":[
    {
        "nombre":"Transporte Marítimo Fluvial ",
        "id":74,
        "Result":[
            {
                "id":268,
                "titulo":"puerto_p_25k",
                "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
                "nombre":"puerto_p_25k",
                "metadato":"",
                "wfs":false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "nombre":"Entidades Territoriales y Unidades Admin ",
        "id":65,
        "Result":[
            {
                "id":239,
                "titulo":"limite_25k",
                "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
                "nombre":"limite_25k",
                "metadato":"",
                "wfs":false
            },
            {
                "id":319,
                "titulo":"administrativo_p_25k",
                "url":"http:\/\/172.17.2.157:8080\/geoserver\/sigtierras\/wms",
                "nombre":"administrativo_p_25k",
                "metadato":"",
                "wfs":false
            }   
        ]
    }
]}
```

Both layers (root and childs) need the same structure. If your root property is called "Result", the child property is also called "Result".

Here is a sencha fiddle with a working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nhd

Comment: Thanks i understand a little more how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your json file anyway. You can use standard reader format:

```
{
root: {
    expanded: true,
    children: [
        { model1_properties },
        { model2_properties, children: [
            {model2_1_properties},
            {model2_2_properties}
        ] },
        { model3_properites }
    ]
}
```

Another way is to change reader properties to make it work (but anyway you'll need to fix your json). See the documentation (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore):

> For the tree to read nested data, the Ext.data.reader.Reader must be configured with a `root` property, so the reader can find nested data for each node (if a `root` is not specified, it will default to `'children'`). This will tell the tree to look for any nested tree nodes by the same keyword, i.e., `'children'`. If a root is specified in the config make sure that any nested nodes with children have the same name. Note that setting `defaultRootProperty` accomplishes the same thing.

You can set `defaultRootProperty` to `'capas'`, but you still need to have Models inside `'capas'` array.

Comment: Thanks I reorganized my json file.